# Researching into the origin of this word: 'Gype' or 'Gyp'

Tags: etymology, slang, pejorative-language

I am trying to research the word *Gype* (at least, I think it is spelt that way.)  I have heard it to describe some people, like "Oh he's a bit of a Gype/Gyp" to mean 'he is a bit of a Gypsy.' The phrase is meant to suggest a dishonest or dirty character.

In Irish it means stupid, and I think in Welsh it means Gypsey.  I am from North Yorkshire, but first heard the saying in the East Riding where is also meant Gypsey.

Has anyone else heard it and can you confirm what it means, please?

Comment: Did you do any research on this question before asking?  The top search results for "gyp definition" and "gyp etymology" completely answer your entire question.

Comment: See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150468/is-jipped-a-politically-incorrect-word

Comment: @Andrew, that question refers to the *verb* "to gyp" (or "jip"), but Jack is asking about the noun.  I've personally never encountered "gyp" as a noun before, but [etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gyp&allowed_in_frame=0) does say it's been used here in the US to mean "a swindle" (which is a third distinct gloss from the two OP quotes).

Comment: *Gyp* and *gippo* are commonly used as nouns. But I deliberately referenced the question rather than close as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have never heard *gyp* used as a noun in Britain, though concur that *gyppo* is a common slang term for a gypsy. There are plenty of other terms many of which are considered very offensive. 'To gyp' about something means to complain, or moan. I had never previously associated it with *gypsy*.

Comment: In Texas fifty years ago, kids (and probably adults, too, although I wasn't one at that time) commonly used the term "a gyp" to refer to an unfair bargain or a misleadingly advertised and disappointing product. I never heard it used to refer to a person, and I never heard its verb form used in the complaining sense that WS2 reports.

Comment: I agree with WS2 - gyp/jip/gip in the UK is either a constant verbal nagging or a constant physical pain as in _my piles are giving me gyp today_. Gyppo/Pikey is a gypsy, and I'd say Gyppo isn't intended to be any more 'derogatory' than Jock or Aussie while Pikey is.

Comment: Yes, in the US of my youth (1950s) "gyp" was a verb/noun commonly used to describe dishonest dealing.  I doubt that there were any actual "gypsies" within a thousand miles, and, to us at the time, "gypsies" were exotic people dressed in colorful clothes who danced a lot, not the target of ridicule.  So the connection between "gyp" and "gypsy" was never made until ca 1970, when folks started being more sensitive to such terms and their origins.

Answer (score 3):

This first edition of OED includes the noun sense of 'gyp' as

> **2.** *U.S. slang.* A thief.
> **1889** in *Century Dict.*

but makes no mention of any relation to *gipsy/gypsy* (or anything else).

Later editions include a 3rd sense of 'gyp'

> **3.** A fraudulent action; a swindle. Also *as adj*. Cf. gyp v. orig. *U.S.*
>
> gyp, v. orig. U.S.
> To cheat, trick, swindle.
> **1889** in *Cent. Dict.*

And so to the Century Dictionary

> **Gipsy, Gypsy** *(abbreviated a lot)* [...] They pursue various nomadic occupations, being tinkers, basket-makers, fortune-tellers, dealers in horses, etc., are often expert musicians, and are credited with with thievish propensities. [...]

Which I think rather sets the tone, for the introduction of *gyp*.

> **gyp** (jip). n. [In the first sense said to be a sportive application of the Greek [greek letters omitted] for vulture, with ref. to their supposed dishonest rapacity; but prob. in this, as in the second sense, an abbr. of *gypsy*, *gypsy* as applied to a sly, unscrupulous fellow]
> **1.** A male servant who attends to college rooms. *(the OED agrees with this citing "**1805** <sub><sup>H. K. WHITE</sup></sub> in Rem. (1819) I. 209 My bed-maker, whom we call a gyp, from a Greek word signifying a vulture, runs away with everything he can lay his hands on." however Grose 1881 Dictionary has the same sense but derived from wolf)*
> **2.** A swindler, especially a swindling horse-dealer; a cheat. *Philadelphia Times*, May 27 1880. [Slang.]

It might be worth noting that The Century Dictionary mentions *gipsery/gipsyry* as

> A colony of Gipsies; a place of encampment for Gipsies.
> Near the city [Philadelphia] are three different *gipseries* where in summer-time the wagon and the tent may be found. *C.G. Leland*, The Gypsies.

I don't think Philadelphia is currently a major concentration of Romani/Gypsy but the timing of the documentation of *gyp* to mean *thief, swindler* coincides quite neatly with the abolition of Romani slavery in Romania (1864) and the subsequent immigration of Romani peoples to West Europe and the east coast of the USA.

So while The Century Dictionary doesn't explicitly say *gyp* is definitely derived from *gipsy*, it does all look like it's pointing that way unless one were to imagine that Philadelphians of the time were acutely aware of the goings on in British universities.

I would think, in general, that most people will assume *gyp* is derived from *gipsy* and is therefore a pejorative, racial slur. Whether it is true or not doesn't really matter; once the majority hold that view then it does become a slur, whether that was the original meaning or not. So it can then be used in the way you describe; to say to someone "You're a gyp" means "You're like a gipsy" (using *gipsy* to mean *a type of person you dislike*).

The modern *chav* could also be racial slur should enough people take up the belief that it is from Romany *chavi, chavo*.

---

**Gype** (in Irish and Scottish) meaning *a fool*. Nothing to do with *gipsy* at all.

Joseph Wright's The English Dialect Dictionary gives

> **GYPE**, V. and sb. Sc. Irel. Also written gipe Dmf.;guipe Ant.
> **1.** v. To stare foolishly ; to act as a fool.
> **2.** sb. A foolish stare. Enff.
> **3.** A fool, lout ; an awkward, stupid fellow.

*Gype* seems pretty close to two other Irish/Scottish words which mean the same thing: *Gaup* and *Gawp*.

> **5.** sb. A vacant, staring person, a fool, simpleton ; also in pi. form.
> **6.** A stupid, vacant stare ; a wild, anxious look

And those two give *Gaupsheet* and *Gawpshite* respectively (Gobshite).

In The Century Dictionary *Gipe, Gype* means *a petticoat, a skirt. An upper frock or cassock*

In OED it is given as *a tunic* (Obs.).

---

And finally, **Pikey**.

The Century Dictionary gives (because it doesn't have *pikey* at all)

> **piker**, n. [pike<sup>3</sup> + -er] A tramp; a vagrant. [Slang]
> The people called in Acts of Parliament sturdy beggars and vagrants, in the old cant language Abraham men, and in the modern *Pikers*. *Borrow*, Wordbook of the English Gypsy Language.

The *pike<sup>3</sup>* is *turnpike*

OED on Abraham-man (wandering but not specifically Romani/Gipsy)

> One of ‘a set of vagabonds, who wandered about the country, soon after the dissolution of the religious houses; the provision of the poor in those places being cut off, and no other substituted.’

OED does have *pikey* and various definitions of *piker*.

> **pikey** *dial*. or *slang*  = **PIKER**<sup>3</sup>
> **1847** <sub><sup>J. O. HALLIWELL</sup></sub> *Dict. Archaic & Provinc. Words 623/2 Piky*, a gipsey. *Kent*.
> **1874** <sub><sup>HOTTEN</sup></sub> *Slang Dict. 253 Pikey*, a tramp or gipsy.
> **1887** <sub><sup>PARISH & SHAW</sup></sub> *Dict. Kentish Dial. 116 Piky*,‥a turnpike traveller; a vagabond; and so generally a low fellow.
> **1955** <sub><sup>P. WILDEBLOOD</sup></sub> *Against Law 125* My family's all Pikeys, but we ain't on the road no more!

**piker**<sup>3</sup> repeats the 1874 citation from *Borrow* that is in The Century Dictionary but predates it with

> **1838** <sub><sup>HOLLOWAY</sup></sub> *Dict. Provinc. 23/2 Cadgers* and pikers are tramps. *E. Suss.*

**piker**<sup>1</sup> is the earliest sense (from 1301), prior to the word gipsy/gypsy/romani/romany, but comes from *pick* not *pike/turnpike*.

> **†1**. A robber, a thief; in later use, a petty thief, pilferer;

but by the mid 1500's this had been replaced by *picker* which we still use in *pick-pocket*.

Wikipedia does quite a good write-up on *pikey* at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pikey but the section about the Medieval Period is almost certainly confusing *pykeris* with *pickers* and the 16th Century section is based entirely on Partridge Dictionary of Slang which merely states that *pikey* derives from C.16 *pike: to depart* without providing any evidence (although it seems sensible enough, *pike* was used in that sense from 1400-now, that *pikey* isn't attested to until 1847 seems a bit of a leap of faith).

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the expression "I was gypped" which meant that the person was cheated and/or ripped off.  After hearing from a person of Romany descent, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people) I learned that this is deeply offensive as its based on the term gypsy and its use perpetuates the negative stereotype that gypsies are dishonest.

Answer (score 0):

I was brought up near York & have heard "Gype " meaning a bit of a slob/dodgey character.

"Its gypee" means cheap/nasty looking & "I've been gyped" means done out of/swindled a lot. They were normal conversation in/aroundway my village in 70-90's. I've been abroad for 17 yrs & still use these words but only round certain company.

Answer (score 0):

I think context and spelling is critical... I'm from Birmingham (UK) and used Gippy or Gyppy or a bit of the Gyp to mean an upset stomach "feeling unsteady"... perhaps as in

gippy
1
/ (ˈdʒɪpɪ) slang /
noun plural -pies
an Egyptian person or thing
Also called: gippo plural -poes a Gypsy
adjective
Egyptian
gippy tummy diarrhoea, esp as experienced by visitors to hot climates

Comment: This is not the meaning mentioned by the OP. Your word has an entirely different etymology.

Answer (score -1):

Gyp in southern Appalachia, USA has two meanings:
1. To cheat or swindle; "That man gypped (jipped) me out of $10 dollars."
2. A female dog old enough to breed but not bred yet: "I have a young gyp hound for sale."

Comment: Can you provide any reference for the second meaning? Your first is already explained at length in Frank's answer.

Comment: I don't see this really answering the question. The question is about "gyp" (noun). In this answer, "gyp" (sense 1) is a verb and "gyp" (sense 2) is an adjective.